# How to use nodemon with JSX?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nodemon

I can compile and run my JSX app with one command:

```
jsx app.jsx | node
```

But I also want my server to automatically restart every time I modify `app.jsx`. I can do that with [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), but I can't quite figure out how to get nodemon to run my script through the JSX compiler beforehand.

I've got a `nodemon.json` file set up like this:

```
{
    "execMap": {
        "js": "node",
        "jsx": "jsx {{filename}} | node"
    },
    "ext": "js jsx",
    "ignore": [
        ".hg",
        "node_modules",
        ".idea"
    ],
    "verbose": true
}
```

But when I run `nodemon` it tells me:

```
8 Feb 21:58:48 - [nodemon] starting `jsx app.jsx | node`
8 Feb 21:58:48 - [nodemon] child pid: 10976
'\"jsx app.jsx | node\"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Which is odd, because that command works verbatim when I paste it directly into my terminal.

Is there any way I get nodemon to run my JSX files?

Comment: Does this work for you? https://github.com/remy/nodemon#specifying-extension-watch-list

Comment: @limelights No. That just tells nodemon which extensions to watch, not how to handle them. I believe it has built-in support for coffeescript, but not jsx.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems nodemon is attempting to run a program with the name you provide, rather than executing a shell.

Create a jsx.sh file with this content:

```
#!/bin/sh
jsx "$1" | node
```

Then `chmod +x jsx.sh`, and put this in your nodemon.json:

```
{
    "execMap": {
        "js": "node",
        "jsx": "./jsx.sh"
    },
    "ext": "js jsx",
    "ignore": [
        ".hg",
        "node_modules",
        ".idea"
    ],
    "verbose": true
}
```

<sup>* not tested</sup>

Comment: I had to use a `.bat` file instead because I'm on Windows, but the idea is the same. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OR you can just locate the jsx command in your `./node_modules/.bin` directory and run it off that instead:

```
    {
        script: "client.js",
        options: {
            execMap: {
                "js": "node",
                "jsx": "./node_modules/.bin/jsx \"$1\" | node"
            },
            ext: "js jsx",
            callback: function (nodemon) {
                nodemon.on("log", function (event) {
                    console.log(event.colour);
                });
            },
            ignore: [
                "node_modules/**/*.js",
                "public/js/**",
                "lib/api/**",
            ]
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Windows (like me) you can create a `.bat` instead of a `.sh` like [FakeRainBrigand suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28415040/65387)

```
@echo off
jsx %1 | node
```

This file has to be in the same directory as `nodemon.json` and `package.json` -- paths don't seem to work in the `execMap` for whatever reason.

---

Also, an even easier solution is to just *not* use any JSX in your main/server script, install [node-jsx](https://github.com/petehunt/node-jsx) and then `require` your JSX files as needed.